# Correlation between r.v.'s following a distribution that is the ration between complex Gaussian and Chi-square r.v.'s

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Given the following two R.V.s

$$z_{1} = \frac{x_{1}}{|x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2 + ... + |x_{M}|^2}$$

and

$$z_{2} = \frac{x_{2}}{|x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2 + ... + |x_{M}|^2}$$

where $x_{i} \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,a), \forall i$ and $a > 1$. As can be seen, the denominator follows a Chi-square distribution with $2M$ degrees of freedom as $x_{i}$ are i.i.d. R.V.s.

Is it possible to calculate

$$\mathbb{E} \{ z_{1} z_{2}^{*}\},$$

and show that the variables are correlated or not? Not that $*$ is the conjugate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First here, by the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality, 
$$E|z_1z^*_2|=E|z_1|\,|z^*_2|\le\sqrt{E|z_1|^2E|z^*_2|^2}=E|z_1|^2<\infty,$$
by [Addition in response to the modification of the OP's original question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290092/distribution-of-ratio-between-complex-gaussian-and-chi-square-r-v-s). 
So, $Ez_1z^*_2$ exists and is finite. 
Therefore and because the joint distribution of the pair $(-z_1,z^*_2)$ is the same as that of $(z_1,z^*_2)$, we conclude that 
$$Ez_1z^*_2=E(-z_1)z^*_2=0.$$

**Detail sdded in response to the OP's comment:** The $x_i$'s are iid and, for each $i$, the distribution of $-x_i$ is the same as that of $x_i$. So, the joint distribution of $(-x_1,x_2,\dots,x_M)$ is the same as that of $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_M)$. Also, $|-x_1|=|x_1|$. So, the random pair
\begin{multline*}
 (z_1,z^*_2)=g(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_M):= \\ 
 \Big(\frac{x_{1}}{|x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2 + \dots + |x_{M}|^2},
 \frac{x_{2}}{|x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2 + \dots + |x_{M}|^2}\Big)  
\end{multline*} 
equals 
\begin{multline*}
 (-z_1,z^*_2)=  
 \Big(\frac{-x_{1}}{|-x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2 + \dots + |x_{M}|^2},
 \frac{x_{2}}{|x_{1}|^2 + |x_{2}|^2 + \dots + |x_{M}|^2}\Big) \\ 
 =g(-x_1,x_2,\dots,x_M)
\end{multline*} 
in distribution, 
as was stated above.

Comment: Dear, thanks. I don't understand the inequality, is this some known one? Could you please, give further details on that?

Comment: The only inequality in the above answer is an instance of the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality, which is now made explicit in the answer.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as the correct one as I have simulated the correlation and it is zero as you pointed out, however, I fail to see how you conclude that the  joint distribution of the pair (−1,∗2) is the same as that of (1,∗2) once the joint pdf is unknown. Is it possible to conclude that without knowing the joint pdf of (1,∗2)? Thanks!

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo : I have added the detail you requested.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now.

Comment: Based on this result and on the knowledge that for $M > 5$ the real and imaginary parts of $z_i \forall i$ are normally distributed with mean equal to 0,  can we say that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are independent?

Comment: I don't think they are. This question, as any other further questions you may have should be asked separately, I think.

Comment: now asked separately at https://mathoverflow.net/q/322555/11260