# Independence of r.v.'s following a distribution that is the ratio between complex Gaussian and Chi-square r.v.'s

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Given the following two R.V.s

$$z_1 = \frac{x_1}{|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_M|^2}$$

and

$$z_2 = \frac{x_2}{|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_M|^2}$$

where $x_i \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,a), \forall i$ and $a > 0$. As can be seen, the denominator follows a Chi-square distribution with $2M$ degrees of freedom as $x_i$ are i.i.d. R.V.s.

Based on these results [(1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322246/correlation-between-r-v-s-following-a-distribution-that-is-the-ration-between-c) and [(2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290092/distribution-of-ratio-between-complex-gaussian-and-chi-square-r-v-s) and on the observation that for $>5$ the real and imaginary parts of $z_i \forall i$ are normally distributed with mean equal to $0,$ can we say that $z_{1}$ and $z_2$ are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The answer is "no":*

Take $M>2$ and evaluate

$$a\,\mathbb{E}[|z_1|^2]=a\,\mathbb{E}[|z_2|^2]=\frac{1}{2M(M-1)},$$
$$a^2\,\mathbb{E}[|z_1|^2|z_2|^2]=\frac{1}{4M(M+1)(M-1)(M-2)},$$
$$\Rightarrow a^2\,\mathbb{E}[|z_1|^2|z_2|^2]-a^2\,\mathbb{E}[|z_1|^2]\mathbb{E}[|z_2|^2]=\frac{1}{2M^6}+{\cal O}(M^{-7}),$$
so $z_1$ and $z_2$ are correlated no matter how large $M$.

Comment: What do you mean by ${\cal O}(M^{-7})$?

Comment: One more question, how did you find $a^2\,\mathbb{E}[|z_1|^2|z_2|^2]=\frac{1}{4M(M+1)(M-1)(M-2)}$?

Comment: ${\cal O}(M^{-7})$ means that the next order term in an expansion in powers of $1/M$ is of order $M^{-7}$; I used _Mathematica_ for the integrals; it will not return an answer for a symbolic $M$, but it will for any integer $M$ and then the polynomial in the denominator is easily obtained; perhaps there is a way to obtain this directly, but to demonstrate the absence of independence of $z_1$ and $z_2$ this suffices.